# How to loop around each possible hex number (00 - FF)

Tags: javascript, hex

If I wanted to loop around numbers 1-10, I would make a loop for i to increment as long as it is less than or equal to 10.

How is this done when you want to loop around a hex number? For example, if someone enters almost all of a MAC address, 12:34:56:78:90:XX, how would I show all the possibilities of what X could be, from 00, to FF?

I have tried giving the values such as `array = { "0", "1" .... "F"}` 
and then changing out i to be one of those each time I loop around, but this just seems massively inefficient.

Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: Loop from 0 to 255 and convert to hex. `toString(16)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.toString(16)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) to get any number in hexadecimal format.

```js
const result = []

for (let i = 0; i <= 0xFF; ++i)
  result.push(i.toString(16))

console.log(result)
```

You might then want to zero pad the first few with [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

```js
const result = []

for (let i = 0; i <= 0xFF; ++i)
  result.push(i.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))

console.log(result)
```

Note, [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Browser_compatibility) is not supported in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hex numbers in JavaScript by prefixing them with `0x`

```js
console.log(0xF)
```

They will be converted to decimal, but it can be easier to use that notation, for example if you want to loop up to `0xFF`.

You can also convert a number to other number bases when [invoking the `.toString` method and supplying a radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

```js
let num = 12;
let otherNum = 255;

console.log(num.toString(16));
console.log(otherNum.toString(16));
```

You can combine the two in order to generate all possible values:

```js
const allValues = [];
for(let i = 0; i <= 0xFF; i++) {
  let num = i.toString(16).toUpperCase();
  
  allValues.push(num);
}

console.log(allValues);
```